# Struggling with cyclical dependencies in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, swift-language

I'm trying to practice TDD, by using it to develop a simple like Bit Vector. I happen to be using Swift, but this is a language-agnostic question.

My `BitVector` is a `struct` that stores a single `UInt64`, and presents an API over it that lets you treat it like a collection. The details don't matter much, but it's pretty simple. The high 57 bits are storage bits, and the lower 6 bits are "count" bits, which tells you how many of the storage bits actually store a contained value.

So far, I have a handful of very simple capabilities:

1. An initializer that constructs empty bit vectors
2. A `count` property of type `Int`
3. An `isEmpty` property of type `Bool`
4. An equality operator (`==`). NB: this is a value-equality operator akin to `Object.equals()` in Java, not a reference equality operator like `==` in Java.

I'm running into a bunch of cyclical dependancies:

1. The unit test that tests my initializer need to verify that the newly constructed `BitVector`. It can do so in one of 3 ways:

   1. Check `bv.count == 0`
   2. Check `bv.isEmpty == true`
   3. Check that `bv == knownEmptyBitVector`

   Method 1 relies on `count`, method 2 relies on `isEmpty` (which itself relies on `count`, so there's no point using it), method 3 relies on `==`. In any case, I can't test my initializer in isolation.
2. The test for `count` needs to operate on something, which inevitably tests my initializer(s)
3. The implementation of `isEmpty` relies on `count`
4. The implementation of `==` relies on `count`.

I was able to partly solve this problem by introducing a private API that constructs a `BitVector` from an existing bit pattern (as a `UInt64`). This allowed me to initialize values without testing any other initializers, so that I could "boot strap" my way up.

For my unit tests to truly be unit tests, I find myself doing a bunch of hacks, which complicate my prod and test code substantially.

How exactly do you get around these sorts of issues?

Comment: You are taking a too narrow view on the term "unit". `BitVector`is a perfectly fine unit size for unit testing and immediately resolves your issues that public members of `BitVector` need each other to make meaningful tests.

Comment: You know too much implementation details up front. Is your development really test-_driven_?

Comment: @herby No, that's why I'm practicing. Although that seems like a really unattainable standard. I don't thing I've ever programmed anything without a pretty clear mental approximation of what the implementation will entail.

Comment: @Alexander You should try to relax that, otherwise it will be test-first, but not test-driven. Just say vague "I'll do a bit vector with one 64bit int as a backing store" and that's it; from that point on do TDD red-green-refactor one after another. Implementation details, as well as API, should emerge from trying to make tests run (the former), and from writing those tests in the first place (the latter).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You're worrying about implementation details too much.

It doesn't matter that *in your current implementation*, `isEmpty` relies on `count` (or whatever other relationships you might have): all you should be caring about is the public interface. For example, you can have three tests:

- That a newly initialized object has `count == 0`.
- That a newly initialized object has `isEmpty == true`
- That a newly initialized object equals the known empty object.

These are all valid tests, and become especially important if you ever decide to refactor the internals of your class so that `isEmpty` has a different implementation that doesn't rely on `count` - so long as your tests all still pass, you know you haven't regressed anything.

Similar stuff applies to your other points - remember to test the public interface, not your internal implementation. You may find TDD useful here, as you'd then be writing the tests you need for `isEmpty` before you'd written any implementation for it at all.

Comment: I suspected so much, but then it doesn't seem I'm writing units tests. From what I've read, I got that the impression that if you break only piece of code, only unit tests directly relating to that code should fail. But alas, that's not the case. Suppose I change the layout of the bit fields in my struct, moving which bits represent the count, but forgot to update the logic in `count`. My tests for `count` would break, and so would the tests for my initializers, and for `isEmpty`, etc. Is that okay?

Comment: @Alexander You sound like a man in need of a clear definition of unit testing. The best one I know comes from [Michael Feathers](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923)

Comment: @candied_orange Could you elaborate on what you suspect I have wrong? I know the value of mocks to isolate tests from network APIs/DBs/file-systems, etc., and everything else in that article was in-line with what I was already thinking

Comment: @Alexander you are treating each method as an independently testable piece of code. That is the source of your difficulties. These difficulties disappear if you test the object as a whole, without trying to divide it into smaller parts. Dependencies between objects are not comparable with dependencies between methods.

Comment: @Alexander "a piece of code" is an arbitrary measurement. Just by initializing a variable you are using many "pieces of code." What matters is that you are testing a *cohesive behavioural unit* as defined by *you*.

Comment: "From what I've read, I got that the impression that if you break only piece of code, only unit tests directly relating to that code should fail."
That seems to be a *very* hard rule to follow. (e.g. if you write a vector class, and you make an error on the index method, you will probably have tons of breakage across all the code that uses that vector class)

Comment: @amon I see. So what's the prescription there, to test the interplay of methods rather than the methods themselves? E.g. rather than testing empty construction, and `isEmpty`, testing the relationship that `BitVector().isEmpty == true`? Should I then also test `BitVector().count == 0`?

Comment: @Alexander From the Michael Feathers link above: "they test a method or the interaction of a couple of methods". Unit tests should verify *transitions* within your code. A single test can verify that isEmpty is true when count == 0. A separate test could verify that isEmpty == false when count != 0.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Alexander Also, look into the "Arrange, Act, Assert" pattern for tests. Basically, you set up the object in whatever state it needs to be in (Arrange), call the method you're actually testing (Act) and then verify that its state changed according to your expectations. (Assert). Stuff you set up in Arrange would be "preconditions" for the test.

Answer (score 5):

> How exactly do you get around these sorts of issues?

You revise your thinking on what a "unit test" is.

An object that manages a mutable data in memory is fundamentally a state machine.  So any valuable use case is going to, at a minimum, invoke a method to put information *into* the object, and invoke a method to read a copy of information out of the object.  In the interesting use cases, you are also going to be invoking additional methods that change the data structure.

In practice, this often looks like

```
// GIVEN
obj = new Object(...)

// THEN
assert object.read(...)
```

or

```
// GIVEN
obj = new Object(...)

// WHEN
object.change(...)

// THEN
assert object.read(...)
```

The "unit test" terminology -- well, it has a long history of not being very good.

> I call them unit tests, but they don't match the accepted definition of unit tests very well -- Kent Beck, Test Driven Development by Example

Kent wrote the first version of SUnit in [1994](https://shebanator.com/2007/08/21/a-brief-history-of-test-frameworks/), the port to JUnit was in 1998, the first draft of the TDD book was early 2002.  The confusion had a lot of time to spread.

The key idea of these tests (more accurately called "programmer tests" or "developer tests") is that the *tests* are isolated from each other.  The tests don't share any mutable data structures, so they can be run concurrently.  There are no worries that the tests must be run in a specific order to correctly measure the solution.

The primary use case for these tests is that they are run by the programmer between edits to her own source code.  If you are performing the red green refactor protocol, an unexpected RED always indicates a fault in your last edit; you revert that change, verify that the tests are GREEN, and try again.  There isn't a lot of advantage in trying to invest in a design where each and every possible bug is caught by only one test.

Of course, is a *merge* introduces a fault, then finding that fault is no longer trivial.  There are various steps you can take to ensure that faults are easy to localize.  See

- Parnas: [On the criteria to be used in decomposing systems into modules](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/05/on-the-criteria-to-be-used-in-decomposing-systems-into-modules/)
- Rainsberger: [Integrated tests are a scam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDfX44fZoMc)
- Shore: [Testing Without Mocks: A Pattern Language](https://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Testing-Without-Mocks.html)

Answer (score 1):

In general (even if not using TDD) you should strive to write tests as much as possible while pretending you don't know how it is implemented.

If you're actually doing TDD that should already be the case. Your tests are an executable specification of the program.

How the call graph looks underneath the tests is irrelevant, as long as the tests themselves are sensible and well maintained.

I think your problem is your understanding of TDD.

Your problem in my opinion is that you are "mixing" your TDD personas. Your "test", "code", and "refactor" personas operate completely independently of each other, ideally. 
In particular your coding and refactoring personas have no obligations to the tests other than to make/keep them running green.

Sure, in principle, it would be best if all tests were orthogonal and independent of each other. But that is not a concern of your other two TDD personas, and it is definitely not a strict or even necessarily realistic hard requirement of your tests. Basically: Don't throw out your common sense feelings about code quality to try to fulfill a requirement that nobody is asking of you.